# Does Orchard have a forum module?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forum, orchardcms

I'm looking for a MVC based forum solution. Does a forum module exist for Orchard or are there any forum modules in development?

**UPDATE:** as of 10/26/11 the MGM.Forum module for Orchard appears to be a work in progress (see [basic-functionality](http://www.themayneissue.com/memorystream/orchard-forums..-basic-functionality) & [mock-ups](http://www.themayneissue.com/memorystream/latest-orchard-forum-mock-ups)) and not yet a valid option. Nothing else exists for Orchard atm so I'm going to give up on a MVC solution and go with YAF.

Comment: I have already searched for an MVC forum but didn't find a fine-tested one. Finally chose YetAnotherForum.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this one http://orchardproject.net/gallery/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.NGM.Forum

I know that it is not an advanced forum module but i don't currently know any other Orchard module.